# Select only non zero values from a matrix using another matrix python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, performance

I have two arrays `mp` of shape (240, 480) and `pop_fts_norm` which is an array of length `N` of arrays of shape (240, 480). I want to create an array of length `N` with values from `mp` but only where elements of `x` are != 0, for each array `x` in pop_fts_norm.

Inefficient code:

```
full_mp = np.array([np.array([mp[i][j] if (x != 0)[i][j] is True else 0 for i in range(240) for j in range(480)]).reshape(240, 480) for x in pop_fts_norm], dtype='float32')
full_mp.shape
```

This works but works slowly.. How can be more efficiently written in pythonic style ?

Thanks,
Petru

Answer (score 2):

```
full_mp = np.array([np.where(x != 0, mp, 0) for x in pop_fts_norm])
full_mp.shape
```

Found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your matrices in the array to a set of 0 and 1, and after that you can just multiply elementwise the two matrix to get the result:

```
for x in pop_fts_norm:
    x[x!=0] = 1

full_mp = np.array([np.array(np.multiply(mp,x) for x in pop_fts_norm])
```